# Browser freezes during javascript eval()

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using eval() in javascript to evaluate a significant amount of js code (not just json, but function calls too). The browser freezes during the call, i.e. the user cannot scroll the browser or click anything. Is there any way around this freezing problem?

Comment: you're going to have to give more detail than that. which browser? what does your code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most browsers, JavaScript runs on the UI thread, so it blocks the UI as you describe. The best way to un-block the UI is to break up the JS into smaller parts, and string them together with setTimeout (which gives control of the thread back to the browser for UI rendering)

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion. It may be difficult to break up your code in proper places to avoid let's say splitting a function on halves and thus triggering an error when evaluating

Answer (score 1):

You may also try executing the code by injecting a new script tag into the page:

```
function executeCode(code) {
    var element = document.createElement('script');
    element.type = 'text/javascript';

    try {
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
    catch (e) {
        element.text = code;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
}

var code = 'alert("hello world");';
executeCode(code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to break up your function into smaller parts. I recommend combining them with `setTimeout`.

In modern browsers there are [web workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/) that can compute data in the background.

Comment: Does the UI rendering resume after each line of code within setTimeout?

Why doesn't the freezing happen when, say, the browser executes a large amount of javascript when loading an initial page?

Comment: That depends on the browser. I believe that the UI freezes only if it's either a) maxing out the CPU b) the javascript manipulates the HTML/CSS. You should do your own testing, I haven't got _any_ data to support my claim.

Comment: The UI *does* block when JavaScript is executed when loading an initial page. Most JavaScript doesn't take that long to run though, so hopefully you don't notice it.